# Nicotine based treatments for animals?

Tags: medicines

The [Australian Poisons Standard](https://www.comlaw.gov.au/Details/F2015L01534) mentions:

> **NICOTINE** *(is allowed)* in preparations containing 3 per cent or less of nicotine when labelled and packed for the **treatment of animals.**

What medications or treatments for animals would include nicotine?

I'm interested in both general treatments (e.g. a wash to get rid of lice) as well as specific products (past or present).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Websearch indicates that currently nicotine is considered too toxic for use and has "no significant use in veterinary practice", but related compounds (nicotinoids) have been used against parasites. (Ref: Handbook of Veterinary Pharmacology, 2013 edition, and the Parisitipedia website)

(Thanks foxd for pointing a typographic error.)